# Difference between if exists (select 1 from) and (select 0 from)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is there any difference at all select 1 from and select 0 from or select any integer from?

I know select * from is a expensive operation.

However, select 1 from differs from select 0 from and or select 29 from?

In the context of just checking if a table/stored procedure exists and if exists, drop it and recreate (In these scenarios)

Comment: It should not since the results are ignored (I usually use `SELECT null`) but you'd have to try it both ways and compare to be certain.

Comment: @DStanley: Thank you, I am not sure how to find the performance differences, also, I never thought of using null, good idea, I will use null and check :) :)

Comment: Run two different queries and compare the time it takes (either manually or looking at the client statistics is SSMS)

Comment: Compare the query plans (CTRL-L). No matter what you put in the select they'll be identical. This takes out any instantaneous I/O or caching impacts when compared to just comparing time taken.

Comment: @DStanley: Thank you, I used client statistics, I could see using * takes less time, although using 1 and 0 etc are just differing by 1. But, using null takes little more higher, but not substantial difference :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your performance would be identical. When you use exists, SQL Server doesn't evaluate anything in the SELECT portion of the statement. It simply resolves to a boolean. This can be proven by doing 1 divided by 0. Normally this would throw an error, but inside an EXISTS, it runs without error.

With regards to your specific use, the expense in the EXISTS check is almost nothing. If you are running into performance issues, it's not the EXISTS part of your script.

Example:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1/0 FROM <TABLE> WHERE 1=1) BEGIN SELECT 'In the exists' END
```

Comment: Ghost, thank you very much, could you please show me with 1/0, I was trying to do that however it gives error to me, maybe my syntax is wrong.

Comment: I really wonder why some of my team leads are ignorant and asked me to use SELECT 1 instead of SELECT * saying about the performance problems without knowing the concepts well.

Comment: @Deevinee as far as your team leads, selecting * is a bad practice when selecting from a table for getting data. If you are selecting * to your app, you are bringing back more data than needed over the wire (which can be expensive). Funny thing is that it is not any more expensive (in my testing) that naming the columns if you need all the columns. So, sometimes I will populate a temp table or table variable and just simply select *; why write out all the columns if you need them all?

Comment: Ghost, First of all thank you very much, I can see no difference in Total Execution Time, when I use 1 or 0 or 1/0, however, I found using * uses less time, just differ by 1 though. I am afraid I didn't understand the difference between using column names and * if I need all columns.However, I will try to understand the difference from the Total Execution Time from the client statistics. Thirdly, my only doubt is in understanding your last statement stating temp table or table variable

Comment: @Deevinee In some stored procedures, I create a temp table or table variable. I use this to store the data I want to send back when the rules start getting very complex. It becomes much more transparent to load more data than needed and start paring it down in the temp table or table variable than writing overly complicated queries. If the temp table/variable has all the fields I want, I normally don't bother specifying the columns.

Comment: Ghost, I am little bad in English, I do not understand what is mean by "paring it down in the temp table ot table variable". I think you are talking about filtering columns? By and large, what I understand is, I use * for selecting all columns into a temp table or table variable. and then to select the columns from temp table or table variable, use the column names